# Laravel Public directory blank page Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am running OS X using XAMPP

I have just installed laravel with the following command:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel5-learning`

I ran this command from the xampp htdocs folder.

Result:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
    Loading from cache

Created project in laravel5-learning
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/process (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/console (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v1.4.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.5.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.20.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.0.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.16.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.11)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing danielstjules/stringy (1.10.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.1.10)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.5.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v1.2.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing mockery/mockery (0.9.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.7.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.5.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.6)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpspec/php-diff (v1.0.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpspec/phpspec (2.2.1)
    Loading from cache

symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-readline (Enables support for arrow-key history navigation, and showing and manipulating command history.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-copy (Allows you to use Copy.com storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.4).)
laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers (~5.3|~6.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing iron-io/iron_mq (Required to use the iron queue driver (~2.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (~2.0).)
fzaninotto/faker suggests installing ext-intl (*)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
phpspec/phpspec suggests installing phpspec/nyan-formatters (~1.0 – Adds Nyan formatters)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
> php artisan key:generate
Application key [Xur8IQttUpPpWLtfXufbHFxrigWz9J5K] set successfully.
roberts-Mac-mini:htdocs robert$
```

So it looks like it installed this successfully.

I put that generated key in the app.php config file.

Laravel docs then state:

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions.
>   Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories
>   should be writable by your web server.

So I did a simple right click `get info` unlock, entered in password and changed the `Read & Write` to everyone on these directories for the simple intention of making it work at the moment.

Refreshed my page: `http://localhost/laravel5-learning/public/`

And still blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: There shouldn't be any key in `app.php`, the key must be in the `.env` file and `app.php` should have `env('APP_KEY')`.

Comment: Have you enabled the php errors? @user2094178 You can use the `app.php` file for your configuration. Laravel will check the `.env` file and if it doesn't find the variable it will check the app.php. But I recommend to use the `.env` file because when you share your code your personal login information won't be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok ran the following command:

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage/`

`sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/`

Working now...

Don't know if this was correct but I works now.

Comment: Laravel need those folder have write permission it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should run this command inside laravel5-learning directory php artisan serve It will work . Also check the file permission once again .